# Join objects with varying thickness

Tags: objects, solidify-modifier

So I'm wanting to join all of these together into one object, but when I do the solidify modifier fits them all the same. Anyway to make it so they stay the thickness they are after joining? Thanks.
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Apply the modifier before you join them

Comment: Welcome, try setting a vertex group on the modifier after joining the objects.

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can see what and how you did it. thx.